# Image is not displaying in ImageUrl

Tags: asp.net, aspxgridview

I am trying to deploy a website with some image referenced from a folder, but the image is not showing up in the website.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="ImagePath" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Catalog/<%#: Item.Product.ImagePath %>" Height="80px" Width="100px"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

This is the current code i am using, where i will use `<%#: Item.Product.ImagePath %>` to get the image into the `ImageUrl` so that it can be displayed. However, when I opened my website, the image is not showing up. After using inspect element to see what went wrong, I see that the `<%#: Item.Product.ImagePath %>` did not display the correct item.

This is what inspect element got:

```
<img id="MainContent_CartList_ImagePath_0" src="Images/Catalog/%7B0%7D.%3C%25#:%20Item.Product.ImagePath%20%25%3E" style="height:80px;width:100px;">
```

however, when I tried to troubleshoot the problem and use `<%#: Item.Product.ImagePath %>` by itself on the website, it shows me the text file of the image.

So if `<%#: Item.Product.ImagePath %>` returns me the `image.jpg`, why is it that when i use it in my `ImageUrl` it has an error and not just run as `"~/Images/Catalog/image.jpg"`?

Comment: `ImageUrl='<%# "~/Images/Catalog/" + Item.Product.ImagePath %>'`

Comment: Hi VDWWD, Just tried the code and it works! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I think the only problem you have is the ":"-character in databinding. It should work without it:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Image ID="ImagePath" runat="server" 
                  ImageUrl="~/Images/Catalog/<%# Item.Product.ImagePath %>" Height="80px" Width="100px"/>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Hi Esko, thanks for the suggestion. I tried removing the `:` and unfortunately it is still not working.